# AWS: Will my account get unexpected charges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My AWS Free Tier is about to expire tomorrow, however I do not longer have active services within my account. I do not plan on using AWS anymore after my Tier expires, but since I do not trust Amazon from charging my credit card, how can I completely make sure I will not? As I said, I don't have active services. Althought I could just completely delete my account, I *may* use it in the future, who knows.

[image: EC2 Dashboard]

Comment: Also confirm that you have no Amazon EBS volumes. If an instance is **Stopped**, it will still have EBS volumes attached, which are chargeable (a few cents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **AWS Cost Explorer**.

From what you're showing, you will not get charged (Security Groups are free). However, take into account that EC2 is just one service of many, and each region has its own set of resources. Cost Explorer may help you identify these. Good luck!